# Data Binding on Interface in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my project structure

ModelInterface

```
|\

|  \



ABC XYZ
```

both implemets `ModelInterface`.

While Data Binding is in Spring.

Usually, what I do:

```
public String hello(@Valid XYZ xyz,BindingResult bindingResult){
}
```

It will create a object of XYZ and then will bind the values.

But, this is what or how I want to use it:

```
ModelInterface modelInterface =new XYZ();
```

In place of `@Valid XYZ`, I want to use `@Valid ModelInterface`

Is it possible to accomplish that in Spring?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: huh... the problem will raise when you have to deserialize your `ModelInterface xyz` input param to concrete class...

Comment: yeah thats what , looking for the way around for the same,if there is any.